# Adding posts from one WordPress site to another WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I have a few WordPress sites I manage and I am trying to show current posts in a box on another page.  The code works but will not update to the new posts.  It has been stuck on the old post for quite some time now.  Here is the code I am using.

```
                  <?php
                        $args = array(
                    'slug' => 'news',
                    'url' => 'metnews.org',
                    'type' => 'post'
        );                          
                      $news = get_transient( 'news-json' );
                      if ( $news == false ) {
                      $news = get_remote_post( $args );
                      set_transient( 'news-json', $news, 60*60*3 );
        }

               echo $news;
        ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is the site you're trying to include the posts on using a caching plugin?

Comment: There are a few Debug plugins that seem to

Comment: Disable them, see if that solves it. The amount of times I've been screwed over thanks to those pesky caching plugins..

Comment: It didn't help.. What is weird is two of the boxes won't update with the new posts but the other two will.. Here is the web site if you want to look at it... http://metrostudentmedia.com/